# different form output with HTML file in subdirectory

Tags: php, html, forms

I've written a fairly straight forward `html` form which when submitted is processed with a separate `php` file.

The `php` produces a booking confirmation `PDF` using the data from the form fields, attaches it to an email then sends the email.

when my `HTML` form page is in the root directory eg *`website.com/booking.html`* it works as intended. It accepts the form, sends the email with the `pdf` attached; no problems at all.

However if I move it into a directory, eg *`website.com/book/`* it returns the output:

> D:\Web\Website Name

I think I must be missing something fairly basic.

Can anyone suggest why I might be receiving the different output inside the sub directory?

Full Code for the PHP file below.

```
<?=
$root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
require_once "$root/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";

$results_messages = array();

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

class phpmailerAppException extends phpmailerException {}

try {
$to = $_POST['email'];
if(!PHPMailer::validateAddress($to)) {
  throw new phpmailerAppException("Email address " . $to . " is invalid -- aborting!");
}
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;
$mail->Host       = "relay.examplehost.com";
$mail->Port       = "25";
$mail->SMTPSecure = "none";
$mail->SMTPAuth   = false;
$mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['realname']);
$mail->From       = "example@example.com";
$mail->FromName   = "Website name";
$mail->addAddress($_POST['email'], $_POST['realname']);
$mail->addBCC("example@example.com", "Enquiries");
$mail->Subject  = "Website Booking Details";

isset($_POST['checkbox1']) && $vehicle = $_POST['checkbox1'];
isset($_POST['checkbox2']) && $vehicle = isset($vehicle) ? $vehicle . ", " . $_POST['checkbox2'] : $_POST['checkbox2'];
isset($_POST['checkbox3']) && $vehicle = isset($vehicle) ? $vehicle . ", " . $_POST['checkbox3'] : $_POST['checkbox3'];
isset($_POST['checkbox4']) && $vehicle = isset($vehicle) ? $vehicle . ", " . $_POST['checkbox4'] : $_POST['checkbox4'];
isset($_POST['checkbox5']) && $vehicle = isset($vehicle) ? $vehicle . ", " . $_POST['checkbox5'] : $_POST['checkbox5'];
isset($_POST['checkbox6']) && $vehicle = isset($vehicle) ? $vehicle . ", " . $_POST['checkbox6'] : $_POST['checkbox6'];
isset($_POST['checkbox7']) && $vehicle = isset($vehicle) ? $vehicle . ", " . $_POST['checkbox7'] : $_POST['checkbox7'];
isset($_POST['checkbox8']) && $vehicle = isset($vehicle) ? $vehicle . ", " . $_POST['checkbox8'] : $_POST['checkbox8'];

// Check for bots
if (strcmp($_POST['checkme'], 'robot')== 0) {
    isset($_POST['redirect']) ? $location = $_POST['redirect'] : $location = "thanks.html";
    header('Location: ' . $location);
     exit;
}

// Convert form data into PDF
require("../fpdf/fpdf.php");
$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial');
$pdf->Image('images/emailheader.jpg');
$pdf->Ln(10);
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Booking Form",0,1,'L');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial');
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Name: {$_POST['realname']}",0,1,'L');
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Company Name: {$_POST['company-name']}",0,1,'L');
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Address: {$_POST['Address']}",0,1,'L');
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Billing Address: {$_POST['billing-address']}",0,1,'L');
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Telephone: {$_POST['Telephone']}",0,1,'L');
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Email: {$_POST['email']}",0,1,'L');
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Deposit Payment: {$_POST['deposit-payment']}",0,1,'L');
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Vehicle Type: {$_POST['vehicle-type']}",0,1,'L');
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Driver Name: {$_POST['driver1-name']}",0,1,'L');
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Driver NI: {$_POST['driver1-NI-number']}",0,1,'L');
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Driver Licence No: {$_POST['driver1-licence-no']}",0,1,'L');
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Driver Licence EXP Date: {$_POST['driver1-licence-exp-date']}",0,1,'L');
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Licence Check Code: {$_POST['driver1-licence-check-code']}",0,1,'L');
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Driver Passport no: {$_POST['driver1-passport-no']}",0,1,'L');
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Driver Passport Exp Date: {$_POST['driver1-passport-exp-date']}",0,1,'L');
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Driver 2 Name: {$_POST['driver2-name']}",0,1,'L');
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Driver 2 NI Number: {$_POST['driver2-NI-number']}",0,1,'L');
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Driver 2 Licence no: {$_POST['driver2-licence-no']}",0,1,'L');
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Driver 2 licence exp date: {$_POST['driver2-licence-exp-date']}",0,1,'L');
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Driver 2 licence check code: {$_POST['driver2-licence-check-code']}",0,1,'L');
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Delivery location: {$_POST['delivery-location']}",0,1,'L');
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Delivery Date: {$_POST['delivery-date']}",0,1,'L');
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Delivery Time: {$_POST['delivery-time']}",0,1,'L');
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Collection Location: {$_POST['collection-location']}",0,1,'L');
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Collection Date: {$_POST['collection-date']}",0,1,'L');
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Collection Time: {$_POST['collection-time']}",0,1,'L');
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Arrival Flight No: {$_POST['arrival-flight-no']}",0,1,'L');
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Arrival Flight time: {$_POST['arrival-flight-time']}",0,1,'L');
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Departure Flight No: {$_POST['departure-flight-no']}",0,1,'L');
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Departure Flight Time: {$_POST['departure-flight-time']}",0,1,'L');
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"More Info: {$_POST['more-info']}",0,1,'L');

$pdf->output('bookings/booking.pdf','F'); 

// Email body
$body = <<<EOT
<a href="https://www.example.com"><img src="https://example.com/images/emailheader.jpg"></a>
<br>
<br>
<table width="660" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td><p><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Thank you; {$_POST['realname']}</font></p>
      <p align="justify"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">We have received your booking details and will contact you shortly. The auto response e-mail verifies your details as supplied. Please make sure you entered your e-mail address and details correctly as this ensures we can respond to your request effectively.<br>
  <br>
  Regards</font></p>
      <p><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> Sales Team <br></font></p>
      <p> <font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"> Information posted as attached</font></p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
EOT;


$file_to_attach = 'bookings/booking.pdf';

$mail->WordWrap = 78;
$mail->msgHTML($body, dirname(__FILE__), true);

//attach the booking form pdf
$mail->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'booking.pdf' );

  //Create message bodies and embed images
// $mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png','phpmailer_mini.png');  // optional name
// $mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer.png', 'phpmailer.png');  // optional name

try {
  $mail->send();
  $results_messages[] = "Message has been sent using SMTP";
}
catch (phpmailerException $e) {
  throw new phpmailerAppException('Unable to send to: ' . $to. ': '.$e->getMessage());
}
}
catch (phpmailerAppException $e) {
  $results_messages[] = $e->errorMessage();
}

isset($_POST['redirect']) ? $location = $_POST['redirect'] : $location = "thanks.html";
header('Location: ' . $location);

//delete PDF from webspace
unlink ('bookings/booking.pdf');

?>
```

Comment: We would need to see some code to be able to help you.

Comment: Show the code from the PHP file which does the processing.

Comment: Sorry, no problem. I've updated the post to include the code at the bottom. I've replaced all real web addresses and email addresses with examples.

Comment: What do you mean by “it returns the output: `D:\Web\Website Name`”? Do you get that as content of the generated PDF file? Does it show up in the browser address bar? Something completely different altogether?

Comment: @CBroe that line is output in the web browser at the top of the page where the page content should be. When this happens it doesn't send an email or generate a PDF, doesn't seem to get that far.

Comment: Then I suggest you insert debug outputs into your script at different positions, to see how far it gets. And it looks like you’re collection possible error/exception messages in an array – but you’re not outputting the contents of that array anywhere by the looks of it.